# Can this function be re-written recursively or more cleanly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This function `match` sets an attribute (collapsed) to true or false depending on
the value of a string :

```
function match(children) {

    var data = $scope.treeData
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var s = data[i]
        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < s.children.length; i2++) {
            var s2 = s.children[i2]
            for (var i3 = 0; i3 < s2.children.length; i3++) {
                for (var i4 = 0; i4 < s2.children[i3].children.length; i4++) {
                    var text = "";
                    if ($scope.searchText == undefined) {
                        text = ""
                    } else {
                        text = $scope.searchText
                    }
                    if (s2.children[i3].children[i4].label
                        .toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()) {
                        s2.children[i3].collapsed = false
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Excluding the bad use of variable names i3,i2 etc is there a cleaner method ?
    As the inner most loop requires access to the outer loop can recursion still be used ?

Update :

Data structure :

```
[{"label":"test","collapsed":false,"children":[{"label":"test","collapsed":false,"children":[],"$$hashKey":"002"}],"$$hashKey":"001"}]
```

Update 2 :

Using a recursive function but the string 'test' is not being matched :

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/19196/

fiddle src :

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">

  </div>
</div>

function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    var json = [{"label":"test","collapsed":false,"children":[{"label":"test","collapsed":false,"children":[],"$$hashKey":"002"}],"$$hashKey":"001"}]

     var searchText = 'test'

     function match(node, searchText){
            angular.forEach(node.children, function(idx, child){
                node.collapsed = child.label.toLowerCase === searchText.toLowerCase
                console.log(node.collapsed)
                if(child.children.length > 0){
                    match(child, searchText);
                }
            });
        }

    match(json, searchText);


}
```

Comment: An extra `}`, I believe copy-paste error

Comment: Do the upper levels contain the property `collapsed` or `label`?

Comment: Also add HTML markup

Comment: What does $scope.treeData look like, could we get an example of that?

Comment: Also, since you're working with Angular, I think this code would look much cleaner if you used angular.forEach

Comment: can you show what does the $scope.treeData contains as DATA

Comment: I want to know the Array content because There can be another better methode

Comment: My guess is may not need any of this if use filters and conditionals in view to do it

Comment: In the html element, use collapsed="item.label == text"

Comment: @Diptox question updated with data structure

Comment: @Tushar your right, } removed thanks

Comment: @blue-sky Is this what your algo is doing? "search for 'text' in leaf nodes and if 'text' matches set the collapsed property of the leaf's parent to false"? Your tree needs to be of a fixed depth with your current algorithm implementation.

Comment: @plalx yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSFiddle is very nearly there.  I made a couple of changes for this [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/19318/).

First, you were passing an array into `match` and not an object.  I changed your `json` variable to be json instead by removing the outer `[]`, but you could also have fixed this by passing in `json[0]`.

The other change was that you had the two parameters, `child` and `idx`, were the wrong way round.

```
function match(node, searchText){
    angular.forEach(node.children, function(child, idx){
        node.collapsed = child.label.toLowerCase === searchText.toLowerCase
        console.log(node.collapsed)
        if(child.children.length > 0){
            match(child, searchText);
        }
    });
}
```

Here's [another](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/19320/) way of doing it, using [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
function match (node, searchText) {
    node.collapsed = node.children.some(function(child) {
        return child.label.toLowerCase === searchText.toLowerCase;
    });
    angular.forEach(node.children, function(child, idx){
        match(child, searchText);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

function match2(obj) {

```
if (obj.children) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
        match2(obj.children[i]);
    }
}
else {
    var text = $scope.searchText ? $scope.searchText : "";

    if (obj.label
            .toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()) {
        obj.collapsed = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this may work for you. I don't know anything about angular there might be something there that would make it easier.

```
var searchText = ($scope.searchText == undefined) ? "": $scope.searchText;
match($scope.treeData, searchText);

function match(node, searchText){
    $.each(node.children, function(idx, child){
        node.collapsed = child.label.toLowerCase === searchText.toLowerCase
        if(child.children.length > 0){
            match(child, searchText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, ive updated slightly to use an angular foreach. can take a look at my question update ?

Comment: the forEach isn't running. I don't know anything about angular does it work the same as a jQuery.each()?

Comment: it should work same, I'll do some more digging, thanks.